# Spring Boot 3 / Tomcat 10 - process invalid cookies

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat

in our Spring Boot 3 app, we are getting this well known discussed error when reading http cookies headers:

*A cookie header was received [g_invalid=x";] that contained an invalid cookie. That cookie will be ignored.*

The previous solution of using Tomcat's `LegacyCookieProcessor` is no longer possible, without reverting back to Tomcat 9, which I don't want to do naturally.

There is no official solution being documented by Spring Boot 3 as to how to handle Version 0 cookies - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/33021 - but its still a common problem, so wondering if other folks have encountered, etc.

The tomcat change-logs dont even mention that `LegacyCookieProcessor` was being removed, which is kinda annoying (as this is where I would expect an alternative to be described - or a reason as to why it was deleted - perhaps..)

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-10.1-doc/changelog.html

Thanks